# sql server to Teradata for Unicode/UTF8 using TPT : Teradata error 6705

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8, teradata, informatica

Few records are going to error due to the following error `6705` as the source have many special character like (îù a¯z’ÇÅÿ )

> 6705   An illegally formed character string was encountered during
>   translation.

All basic set up is good:

- Source and target have the same Unicode data set
- Both Source and TGT have the UTF encoding
- odbc.ini for sql server has the required code page (106)

**Questions:**

1. is their any entry for TPT to check in any file?
2. any way to convert all special character to recognized teradata value
3. any other inputs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like internal Teradata problem, not related to either SQL Server nor Informatica, please compare: https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035_1096_109A/Database.05.2268.html.

It should not be caused just by Unicode characters within your data. I don't think this is the problem. But perhaps one of those:

```
A SO is followed by MBCs, then the end of the string.
A SO is followed by SBCs, before encountering a shift-in (SI).
```

Can you try to verify this and provide some more details?